# Switch case accepting value from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="a"></p>
  <script>
    //switch
    var sb;
    document.write("<br><input type='text' id='a'> <button onclick='casss()'>Show Value</button>");
    sb = document.getElementById('a').value;

    function casss() {
      switch (sb) {
        case 1:
          sb = "php";
          break;
        case 2:
          sb = "html";
          break;
        case 3:
          sb = "css";
          break;
        case 4:
          sb = "javascript";
          break;
      }
      document.write("<br>" + sb);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Accept value from textbox and match the case in switch and print the text in that case?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you encounter any errors? What were they? Please ask specific questions to increase your chances of getting good feedback.

Comment: when i pass '1' in textbox it should give 'php' on click of the button but it gives '1' only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. There is already a `<p>` element with `id='a'`. Either remove that or change that id to make it unique.
2. Your `switch` case expects integer value in `case` condition so use `parseInt(sb)` inside `switch` parameter.

```js
    //switch
    var sb;
    document.write("<br><input type='text' id='a'> <button onclick='casss()'>Show Value</button>");
    function casss() {
      sb = document.getElementById('a').value;
      switch (parseInt(sb)) {
        case 1:
          sb = "php";
          break;
        case 2:
          sb = "html";
          break;
        case 3:
          sb = "css";
          break;
        case 4:
          sb = "javascript";
          break;
      }
      document.write("<br>" + sb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using document.write here, there are far better ways to add elements to the page, and this also seems to be causing the function not to execute.

You also need to move the line `var sb = document.getElementById('a').value;` inside your `casss()` function, because otherwise it will only read the value of the textbox once when it's first created, whereas you want to get the latest value every time the button is pressed.

Demo (using static markup instead of document.write):

```js
    //switch

    function casss() {
      var sb = document.getElementById('a').value;
      console.log(sb);
      switch (sb) {
        case 1:
          sb = "php";
          break;
        case 2:
          sb = "html";
          break;
        case 3:
          sb = "css";
          break;
        case 4:
          sb = "javascript";
          break;
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerText = sb;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<br><input type='text' id='a'> <button onclick='casss()'>Show Value</button>
  <p id="a"></p>
  <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```